# How do I determine the indexPath for cell with a switch that has been tapped?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiswitch

I have a UITableView with prototype cells that have a UISwitch on them.  When the user taps the switch on any particular cell, I need to determine which object in my datasource has had its switch toggled.

Here is my method for the switch:

```
- (IBAction)completeSwitchTapped:(id)sender {
      UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[sender superview];
      NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.itineraryTableView indexPathForCell:cell];


      NSLog(@"cell row is: %d in section: %d", indexPath.row, indexPath.section);
}
```

But this always returns row 0 in section 0 regardless of which row or section was picked.

How do I properly return the correct cell which contains the switch?  Clearly `[sender superview]` isn't working and I'm considerably at a loss for how to reference the cell.

Thanks!

Comment: did you check your view hierarchy? Make sure your `UISwitch` is a subview of the cell?

Comment: if you log cell, you will see that it's not actually a UITableViewCell.

Comment: Set the `tag` of the switch with an identifier meaningful to you.

Comment: To expand on rdelmar's comment: `sender` is an object of type `UISwitch`, not of type `UITableViewCell`. Keeping that in mind, the answers already given may make more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
UIView *superview = sender.superview;
while (![superview isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]] && superview.superview != nil) {
    superview = superview.superview;
}
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.itineraryTableView indexPathForCell:superview];
```

Comment: This worked, but rather than superview.superview I had to go with [superview superview] and rather than sender.superview I had to use [sender superview].  I'm not sure why dot notation wasn't working there.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When creating the button/switch, set it's tag to the cell row or some other meaningful value.  Then simply extract `sender.tag` when the IBAction method is invoked, to retrieve the cell row.

Answer (score 0):

When I have to do buttons and switches like this in my own tables, I usually subclass UIButton or UISwitch and in my subclass, I add a "`.indexPath`" or "`.row`" property to my subclassed control.

Which I set when I return the freshly populated (or reset) table view cell in "`cellForRowInIndexPath:`"

That way, when your switch or button is touched, you'll have a property that has the correctly set row index ready for you to work with.

A much more straightforward & less janky solution versus doing "`superview.superview`".

Comment: This sounds good, but I hate subclassing simple controls.  I know the superview.superview solution sounds janky but I think it's easy to see in the code (now that I know what to do).  Thanks though!  Great idea for later things...